# Найти пересечение списков, которые содержат разные типы элементов. При этом не используя встроенные методы работы со списками. Python

Tags: python, list

```
l1 = [3, 0, 8, 7.2, 'r', 3, True, [8, 2], 0.22, 'ee', 'r']
l2 = [3, 4, 6, 'r', 7.2, 33, 3, 0.22, 'r', 'r', [8, 2]]
```

Результат должен быть

```
[3, 3, 7.2, 'r', 'r', [8, 2], 0.22]
```

Элементы могут идти в любом порядке

Был вот такой вариант, но препод его принял, т.к. "слишком слишком много циклов" `

```
c = []
count_a = 0
count_b = 0
for i in a:
    if i in c:
        continue
    for j in b:
        if i == j:
            for u in a:
                if i == u:
                    count_a += 1
            for u in b:
                if i == u:
                    count_b += 1
            count = min(count_a, count_b)
            for _ in range(count):
                c += [i]
                count_a = 0
                count_b = 0
            break
```

Есть идея. Разбить списки по типам, отсортировать их, отдельно каждые подравнивать, и слепить обратно.
Препод сказал, что можно использовать функцию del, но я хз где тут ее можно всунуть.
Также нельзя забывать о том, что если в l1 есть 2 одинаковых елем. и в l2 они есть, то и на выходе в списке должны быть 2 это елем.
Пожалуйста помогите, а то

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3):

задача O(n^2):

1. идете по первому списку
2. находите во втором первый одинаковый элемент и
3. заносите его в новый список
4. удаляете его из второго

код:

```
l1 = [3, 0, 8, 7.2, 'r', 3, True, [8, 2], 0.22, 'ee', 'r']
l2 = [3, 4, 6, 'r', 7.2, 33, 3, 0.22, 'r', 'r', [8, 2]]

res = []

for src in l1:
    for dst_index in range(len(l2)):
        if src == l2[dst_index]:
            res.append(src)
            del(l2[dst_index])
            break

print(res)
```

Comment: `del` это не функция

Answer (score 0):

В конце вопроса есть фраза "Разбить списки по типам, отсортировать их ...". То есть, списки разнотипные, но если в этих списках элементы одного типа, то они могут быть упорядочены - к ним можно применять операцию `<`. Разнотипные списки можно преобразовать в списки, которые можно сортировать даже если типы элементов различны:

```
def decorate(seq):
    return ((id(type(v)), v) for v in seq)
```

Идея в том чтобы элементы списков заменить на пары `(число, элемент)`. Числа равны только для элементов одного типа. Такой список можно сортировать, при сравнении пар никогда не будут сравниваться элементы разных типов.

Для поиска общих элементов в списках (которые будем считать упорядоченными) нужна будет процедура, наподобие `merge` в алгоритме сортировки слиянием:

```
def intersect_iters(it1, it2):
    read1, read2 = True, True
    while True:
        if read1:
            try:
                v1 = next(it1)
            except StopIteration:
                return

        if read2:
            try:
                v2 = next(it2)
            except StopIteration:
                return

        if v1 < v2:
            read1, read2 = True, False
        elif v2 < v1:
            read1, read2 = False, True
        else:
            read1, read2 = True, True
            yield v1
```

Собирая всё вместе:

```
def decorate(seq):
    return ((id(type(v)), v) for v in seq)


def undecorate(seq):
    return (v[-1] for v in seq)


def intersect_iters(it1, it2):
    read1, read2 = True, True
    while True:
        if read1:
            try:
                v1 = next(it1)
            except StopIteration:
                return

        if read2:
            try:
                v2 = next(it2)
            except StopIteration:
                return

        if v1 < v2:
            read1, read2 = True, False
        elif v2 < v1:
            read1, read2 = False, True
        else:
            read1, read2 = True, True
            yield v1


def intersect(seq1, seq2):
    return undecorate(
        intersect_iters(
            iter(sorted(decorate(seq1))),
            iter(sorted(decorate(seq2)))
        )
    )


l1 = [3, 0, 8, 7.2, 'r', 3, True, [8, 2], 0.22, 'ee', 'r']
l2 = [3, 4, 6, 'r', 7.2, 33, 3, 0.22, 'r', 'r', [8, 2]]

print(list(intersect(l1, l2)))
```

> ```
> $ python list_intersection.py 
> [0.22, 7.2, [8, 2], 3, 3, 'r', 'r']
> ```